# SQL in Athena working fine with "limit 10" but not working without "limit"

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to fetch some data from Athena DB which is generated from Glue Crawler. When I am applying "limit 10" SQL is working fine. But when I am issuing the following SQL, that is not working. The total size of those four tables are not bigger than 5GB

```
SELECT
date_parse(cdh.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') "Hour"
, cdh.hour_of_day "Hour of Day"
, hcm.max_concurrent_usage "Concurrent Usage"
, hqm.max_license_quantity "License Quantity"
, lm.license_id
FROM
(((db20221117.calender_dimension_hourly cdh
LEFT JOIN db20221117.hourly_concurrent_measure hcm ON (cdh.sid_hourly = hcm.sid_hourly))
LEFT JOIN db20221117.hourly_quantity_measure hqm ON (cdh.sid_hourly = hqm.sid_hourly))
LEFT JOIN db20221117.license_dimension lm ON (lm.license_id = hcm.license_id and lm.license_id = hqm.license_id))
```

Please advise

I tried in Athena Query Editor and was expecting some pages with data. The query is running and timeout is happening everytime.

Comment: Did you check with limit 100? If that works, do check your Per-query data usage limits?

Comment: @Rishabh Sahrawat:  Yes, I tried with limit 100 and even 10000. works correctly with those limit values. but not working when I am removing the limit.

By the way, where to check per query data usage limit? Where to set that?

Comment: Hi @RishabhSahrawat : I checked that part. There is no data limit in Athena query

Comment: I am guessing then it has something to do with the query analysis itself, resulting in big size.

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat - yes that result set is really big. But is there any limitation of Athena query result size?